# Overriding setter on domain class in grails 1.1.2

Tags: grails, dns, overriding, grails-orm, setter

I have following two domain classes in Grails 1.1.2:

```
class A implements Serializable {
 MyEnumType myField
 Date fieldChanged

 void setMyField(MyEnumType val) {
  if (myField != null && myField != val) {
   myField = val
   fieldChanged = new Date()
  }
 }
}

class B extends A {
 List children
 void setMyField(MyEnumType val) {
  if (myField != null && myField != val) {
   myField = val
   fieldChanged = new Date()
   children.each { child -> child.myField = val }
 }
}
```

When I set B instance's myField, I get the setter into the cycle... myField = val line calls setter again instead of assiging the new value.

Any hint how to override the setter correctly? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the `this` keyword to avoid calling the getter or setter:

```
this.myField = val
```

See http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Beans#GroovyBeans-Propertyandfieldrules